# Why is a bad SQL Server execution plan cached for a non-stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Many of the QA's I've seen on this subject involve stored procedures. I'm using C# and ADO.NET to execute a SQL Server `select` query (not a stored procedure).

The query was using a lot of IO's and was slow, so I created a new index. Now, if I run the same query with `OPTION(RECOMPILE)`, I get a quick response with a small number of IO's.

However, if I don't include the `OPTION(RECOMPILE)` on the `select` statement, I continue to get the slow, high IO results. I've tried to clear the execution plan cache using `DBCC FREEPROCCACHE` to no avail.  I've also ran an `UPDATE STATISTICS`.

It seems like a bad plan is being recreated every time the query is run. Should I just change the code to include the `OPTION(RECOMPILE)`, or is there something else going on?

Here is the query.  I'm runing it from it from SSMS.

```
SET STATISTICS IO ON;

DECLARE @request_date datetime

SELECT @request_date='1/24/2017'
SELECT TOP 300 
pr.[mr_entry_id], 
mr.[source_code] AS accession_no, 
mr.[patient_id], 
pr.[rx_location], 
CASE WHEN pr.[product_id] IS NULL THEN 'Compound' ELSE 'Product' END AS product_type, 
mr.[description], 
SUBSTRING(r.[fname],1,1) + ' ' + r.[lname] AS requested_by, 
rs.[short_name] AS status, mr.[category], 
CASE WHEN mr.[date_recorded] >= '12/16/2009' THEN pr.[date_requested] ELSE NULL END AS date_recorded, 
CASE WHEN mr.[date_recorded] >= '12/16/2009' THEN v.[lname] + ', ' + v.[fname] ELSE '' END AS requester, 
mr.[request_finalized_date], 
SUBSTRING(u.[fname],1,1) + ' ' + u.[lname] AS clinician, 
pr.[is_onfile], 
pr.[is_outside_prescription] 
FROM [rx_request] pr 
INNER JOIN [mr_entry] mr ON pr.[mr_entry_id] = mr.[id] 
INNER JOIN [request_status] rs ON (rs.rc_id = 25000 and pr.[status_id] = rs.[status_id]) 
LEFT OUTER JOIN [vmis_user] v ON pr.[requester] = v.[id] 
LEFT OUTER JOIN [client] rc ON mr.[request_rc_id] = rc.[id] 
LEFT OUTER JOIN [vmis_user] u ON mr.[request_clinician_id] = u.[id] 
LEFT OUTER JOIN [vmis_user] r ON mr.[request_finalized_id] = r.[id] 
WHERE mr.[class] = 'Medication' 
AND mr.[is_request] = 1 
AND mr.[finalized_date] BETWEEN @request_date AND DATEADD(d,1,@request_date) 
AND rs.[rc_id] = 25000 
AND mr.[is_finalized] = 1 
OPTION(RECOMPILE)
```

Comment: Are you using any variables in your query perhaps? Possible to share the query and indexes you've created?

Comment: SQL Server uses statement-level optimization, so a query in a stored procedure is optimized and the plan is cached the same way, whether it's in a stored procedure or not.

Comment: Can you share your query? You can use query hints to adjust, or based on type of query (like a search query with lots of optional parameters), it may be best to use dynamic SQL to get optimum query plan.

Comment: have you tried the same query direct in SSMS ? Is it still slow there ?

Comment: As to why you're consistently getting a bad plan, if you look in the query plan XML (both for your poorly performing version and the one with `OPTION(RECOMPILE)`), you can find the values for parameters that were used to compile the query. Look for `ParameterCompiledValue`). Are there quality/cardinality differences in those parameters between the two plans?